Cannot Load Firmware to the board
I am a newbie and was playing with esp32c3 with rust.
I was able to build a sample blinky project but cannot load into the board. I am running ubuntu on WSL.
When I tried running 'espflash board-info --list-all-ports', its showing my board, which is '/dev/ttyACM0', but then 'Connecting...'. That's it. Nothing else is happening and I have to kill the process to come out of it.
When I run 'espflash flash target/riscv32imc-esp-espidf/debug/blinky-rust-esp32c3', it says no serial ports detected.

Can someone help me here?
Thanks in advance.
When I tried running 'espflash board-info --list-all-ports', its showing my board, which is '/dev/ttyACM0', but then 'Connecting...'. That's it. Nothing else is happening and I have to kill the process to come out of it.
I tried editing '.cargo/config.toml' by adding my serial port '/dev/ttyACM0' in the runner field, but that didn't help.

Does anything in unable to flash esp32. the port doesn't exist help?

I tried, but no use. Now I was able to run  'espflash board-info --list-all-ports'. But not for running 'espflash' command. I didn't press the boot button for flashing. But still I am not able to flash to the board. I am getting  'uqfcg@DESKTOP-10L1NMP:~/esp/gettingStarted/blinky-rust-esp32c3$ espflash flash target/riscv32imc-esp-espidf/debug/blinky-rust-esp32c3lsusb
Error: espflash::no_serial
× No serial ports could be detected
help: Make sure you have connected a device to the host system. If the device is connected but not listed, try using the --list-all-ports flag'.
'

Could you do it directly from Windows instead of WSL?

USB-UART serial adapters (e.g. the FTDI chip on ESP32 devkits) don't automatically appear in WSL (because they're not serial ports, they're USB devices). You need to go through the standard song-and-dance of USB passthrough from Windows to WSL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/connect-usb. Or just use native Windows/Linux, if that's an option.

I have connected to windows and I have attached this serial port into my wsl2. I am able to successfully run 'espflash board-info --list-all-ports', and it is showing my serial port. But the issues comes when I run 'espflash flash target/riscv32imc-esp-espidf/debug/blinky-rust-esp32c3lsusb'. Its saying 'Error: espflash::no_serial'.
